# RegExp formatting error in google-apps-scripts

Tags: regex, google-apps-script

I'm trying to write a google-apps-script that will parse price listings out of a document and my first step was to extract just the prices from the report.

```
function createAndSendDocument() {
 var labelObject = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("Oil Prices");
 var bodyRe = new RegExp("(?:Company Name Town Price Phone. Date Calc)(.*)(?=Oil prices quoted on this Website.*)","m");

 var threads = labelObject.getThreads(0, 30);
 for (var i = 0; i < threads.length; i++) {
   var massageObject = threads[i].getMessages()[0];
   var htmlDoc = Xml.parse(massageObject.getBody(), true);
   var myArray = bodyRe.exec(htmlDoc.getElement().getElement("body").Text);
 }

}
```

The problem is that the RegExp appears to work correctly in [www.rubular.com](http://www.rubular.com/r/CXjNSMDedp) (permalink) but in the debugger for google scripts is evaluating different.  Are there differences in rules here?

Text:

> The page http://www.newenglandoil.com/rhodeisland/zone2.asp?x=0 has
>   changed since the previous check.
>
> ------ changes ------  New England Home
>
> Back to Rhode Island  Home
>
> REQUEST SPECIAL OFFERS
>                            FROM YOUR LOCAL FUEL DEALERS
>
> Oil Dealer
>
> 2 Week Free Trial
>       Suggest a Dealer
>
> [Northern Rhode Island.]
>         Click on banners below for more company information
>       Below are oil prices for Northern Rhode Island      High  0     Low 0
>          Average 0
>       Company Name Town Price Phone# Date Calc
>       PRICERITE OIL INC
>   -    PAWTUCKET   $3.210  6/14/2013  DUPUIS OIL CO
>   +    PAWTUCKET   $3.160  6/26/2013  DUPUIS OIL CO
>       PAWTUCKET  $3.499    6/18/2013
>       PROFESSIONAL HEATING SERVICE
>   -    NORTH PROVIDENCE   $3.120  6/25/2013  MALONEY'S OIL
>   +    NORTH PROVIDENCE   $3.120  6/26/2013  MALONEY'S OIL
>       PAWTUCKET  $3.450    6/18/2013
>       A-STAR OIL
>   -    CUMBERLAND  $3.120  6/24/2013  UNIVERSAL OIL COMPANY
>   +    CUMBERLAND  $3.120  6/26/2013  UNIVERSAL OIL COMPANY
>       CUMBERLAND  $3.230  6/21/2013  AFFORDABLE FUEL
>       SEEKONK  $3.160  6/25/2013  RAMBONE & SPRAQUE OIL SERVICE INC.
>       NORTH SCITUATE  $3.350  6/18/2013  THRIFTY OIL
>       TIVERTON  $3.199  6/19/2013  DISCOUNT OIL BROKERS
>       SMITHFIELD  $3.249  6/18/2013  T H MALLOY & SONS
>       CUMBERLAND  $3.499    6/18/2013
>       HENRY OIL COMPANY
>       CUMBERLAND  $3.600  6/18/2013  GLOW OIL
>   -    LINCOLN  $3.190  6/25/2013  RI OIL CLUB
>   +    LINCOLN  $3.190  6/26/2013  RI OIL CLUB
>       NORTH PROVIDENCE  $3.349  6/18/2013  Oil prices quoted on this Website are based upon information provided
>       by oil dealers, without independent verification by Energy Data, LLC.
>       Energy Data, LLC makes no representation or warranty regarding the
>       price, quality, delivery or availability of oil by the dealers referred
>       to on this Website.
>
> *prices subject to change
>
> COPYRIGHT © 2011 Energy Data, LLC, All rights reserved.
>
> ------------------- End of page report -----------------------

Google Scripts Results:

> ["CE \xa0$3.349 \xa06/18/2013 \xa0", "E \xa0$3.349 \xa06/18/2013
>   \xa0"]

Rubular Results:

> 1. PRICERITE OIL INC
>
>    - PAWTUCKET   $3.210  6/14/2013  DUPUIS OIL CO
>    - PAWTUCKET   $3.160  6/26/2013  DUPUIS OIL CO
>        PAWTUCKET  $3.499    6/18/2013
>        PROFESSIONAL HEATING SERVICE
>    - NORTH PROVIDENCE   $3.120  6/25/2013  MALONEY'S OIL
>    - NORTH PROVIDENCE   $3.120  6/26/2013  MALONEY'S OIL
>        PAWTUCKET  $3.450    6/18/2013
>        A-STAR OIL
>    - CUMBERLAND  $3.120  6/24/2013  UNIVERSAL OIL COMPANY
>    - CUMBERLAND  $3.120  6/26/2013  UNIVERSAL OIL COMPANY
>        CUMBERLAND  $3.230  6/21/2013  AFFORDABLE FUEL
>        SEEKONK  $3.160  6/25/2013  RAMBONE & SPRAQUE OIL SERVICE INC.
>        NORTH SCITUATE  $3.350  6/18/2013  THRIFTY OIL
>        TIVERTON  $3.199  6/19/2013  DISCOUNT OIL BROKERS
>        SMITHFIELD  $3.249  6/18/2013  T H MALLOY & SONS
>        CUMBERLAND  $3.499    6/18/2013
>        HENRY OIL COMPANY
>        CUMBERLAND  $3.600  6/18/2013  GLOW OIL
>    - LINCOLN  $3.190  6/25/2013  RI OIL CLUB
>    - LINCOLN  $3.190  6/26/2013  RI OIL CLUB
>        NORTH PROVIDENCE  $3.349  6/18/2013

Thanks

Comment: Try using http://regexpal.com/ for testing JavaScript Regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
var bodyRe = new RegExp("Company Name Town Price Phone. Date Calc([^>]*?(?=Oil prices quoted on this Website[^>]*))");
```

since your text has newlines, and in javascript the .* does not match newline, but this does: [^>]*  (which means repeat any character including newlines, other than > character)

Then, myArray[1] should be your required output.

Comment: That did it, great to know.  I'm curious if you can suggest a better reference than I have (since that was not mentioned) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions